# Css for U shape with arrow

Tags: html, css

Im looking for css which generates curve with arrow at end. I  have attached image what im looking for.

I have tried multiple ways but cant match it.

Please help me!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIms8.jpg)

Comment: That's pretty cool.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: *I have tried multiple ways* – could you share some of those with us?

Comment: I have tried border radius for u shape and another div for arrow shape. Cant get u shape with border radius also partial part of line need to overridden with arrow which i tried with background color for arrow div and floated over u shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```css
.icon-container {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80px;
}

#curve {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #999;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
#arrow {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 63px;
    transform: rotateZ(5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
    <div id="curve"></div>
    <div id="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am only answering this because 1) I have already done it, so it's copy and paste.  And 2) because you tried to *explain* us what you attempted, however you should have posted your code that you'd written yourself.

```css
        .div_1 {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .div_2 {
            background-color: #FFF;
            height: 302px;
            width: 175px;
            margin-left: 50%;
        }
        .arrow-right {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: 45px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
            border-left: 45px solid #000;
            top: 265px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="div_1">
    <div class="div_2">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```